# C++, Is static initialisation performed by multiple threads?

Tags: c++, multithreading

In C++, do I have to worry about multiple threads operating on an object during static initialisation or is it guaranteed to be performed by a single thread?

Comment: usually static initialization is done when application starts, so there is only one thread at this time

Comment: As far as I know it is guaranteed to be done by only one thread as of C++11. I'll bet someone can cite the standard in an answer. It might be good to clarify whether you mean a static variable in a function body or a static global or class member, the rules are different

Comment: What would occur in your object's initialization that makes you wary of multithreading?

Comment: I was thinking of static globals.

Comment: The thing I wanted to do was to declare static variables in multiple class implementations and have them added to common container (and yes, I know that I can't guarantee the order of static initialisation and so I need to initialise the container in a funtion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For global-scoped `static` variables, yes.

For local `static`s (declared inside functions), this guarantee only holds in C++11 and after.

Comment: Hi Luchian, do you mean that "yes, I do need to worry about multiple threads" or "yes, it's guaranteed, in C++11 and after, to be performed by a single thread"?

Answer (score 0):

One little caveat: do any of your global-scope static objects spawn threads from their constructors? If so, those threads will be running during static initialization time.